# Lazax ally advantage conditions

Tags: rex

In Rex Lazax ally advantage allows Lazax player to give influence to an ally before she makes a legal bid on a strategy card. The tricky point which prompted questions when we played is: *is the ally required to have sufficient amount of influence to make a bid **before** Lazax gives him some*?
E.g.: Sol is allied with Lazax but has no influence, so he cannot make a bid by himself. Can he receive influence from Lazax in such situation to make a bid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ally does not need to have enough to make the bid before the transfer, as long as the ally has enough to

The rulebook indicates:

> The Lazax may give his ally any amount of influence during this
>   Bidding Phase. This influence must be given before the player makes a
>   legal bid on the current Strategy card.  The ally
>   is not required to bid all of the influence given

(Note the implication that the ally is very much allowed to bid influence that has just been given.)

Then, in the rules for bidding:

> **Bid:** If a player wishes to bid, he announces how much influence he is
>   willing to pay for the card. ... A player cannot bid more influence
>   than he has in his reserve.

The transfer from the Lazax comes before the player makes the bid, and the requirement is only that the player has enough to cover the bid at the time the player makes the bid.

In your example, Sol would be able to receive influence from Lazax and then subsequently make a bit with it.